# How can I update my dictionary with nested HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, axios

I'm gonna try to explain this as clearly as I can, but it's very confusing to me so bear with me.

For this project, I'm using Node.js with the modules Axios and Cheerio.

I am trying to fetch HTML data from a webshop (similar to Amazon/eBay), and store the product information in a dictionary. I managed to store most things (title, price, image), but the product description is on a different page. To do a request to this page, I'm using the URL I got from the first request, so they are nested.

This first part is done with the following request:

```
let request = axios.get(url)
  .then(res => {
    // This gets the HTML for every product
    getProducts(res.data);
    console.log("Got products in HTML");
  })
  .then(res => {
    // This parses the product HTML into a dictionary of product items
    parseProducts(productsHTML);
    console.log("Generated dictionary with all the products");
  })
  .then(res => {
    // This loops through the products to fetch and add the description
    updateProducts(products);
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  })
```

I'll also provide the way I'm creating product objects, as it might clarify the function where I think the problem occurs.

```
function parseProducts(html) {
  for (item in productsHTML) {
    // Store the data from the first request
    const $ = cheerio.load(productsHTML[item]);
    let product = {};
    let mpUrl = $("a").attr("href");
    product["title"] = $("a").attr("title");
    product["mpUrl"] = mpUrl;
    product["imgUrl"] = $("img").attr("src");
    let priceText = $("span.subtext").text().split("\xa0")[1].replace(",", ".");
    product["price"] = parseFloat(priceText);

    products.push(product);
  }
}
```

The problem resides in the updateProducts function. If I console.log the dictionary afterwards, the description is not added. I think this is because the console will log before the description gets added. This is the update function:

```
function updateProducts(prodDict) {
  for (i in prodDict) {
    let request2 = axios.get(prodDict[i]["mpUrl"])
      .then(res => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data);
        description = $("div.description p").text();
        prodDict[i]["descr"] = description;
        // If I console.log the product here, the description is included
      })
  }
// If I console.log the product here, the description is NOT included
}
```

I don't know what to try anymore, I guess it can be solved with something like async/await or putting timeouts on the code. Can someone please help me with updating the products properly, and adding the product descriptions? Thank you SO much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refactor this with async/await one would do:

```
async function fetchAndUpdateProducts() => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);

    getProducts(response.data);
    console.log("Got products in HTML");

    parseProducts(productsHTML);
    console.log("Generated dictionary with all the products");

    await updateProducts(products);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

fetchAndUpdateProducts().then(() => console.log('Done'));
```

and

```
async function updateProducts(prodDict) {
  for (i in prodDict) {
    const response = await axios.get(prodDict[i]["mpUrl"]);
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    description = $("div.description p").text();
    prodDict[i]["descr"] = description;
  }
}
```

This will not proceed to conclude the call to fetchAndUpdateProducts unless the promise returned by updateProducts has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks for answering, do I have to call fetchAndUpdateProducts manually after updating?

Comment: In your code snippet above I don't see the context in which you are running the request. To replicate the behaviour of your code you would need to call the async function.